# Find whether user is running iPhone OS 2.x or 3.0

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is there any way I can find out in my app if the user is running it on a device with OS 2.x or 3.0?

I tried adding a tag like the iPhone project templates do, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
#ifndef __IPHONE_3_0
//MY CODE FOR 3.0 GOES HERE
#else
//2.x CODE HERE
#endif
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure for the reason for the down vote, I think the question is good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]`. This will contain the version string.

Answer (score 2):

```
#ifndef __IPHONE_3_0
#define __IPHONE_3_0 30000
#endif
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= __IPHONE_3_0
    [[startButton titleLabel] setFont:playFont];
#else
    [startButton setFont:playFont];
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to do, it is better to test for functionality rather than a specific version.